# Voodoo Code In Python

Tags: python

I was going through Zed Shaw's Learn Python The Hard Way and something in Chapter 15 struck me. In the extra credit exercises he asks us to delete the latter part of the code [everything after print txt.read() ] and then execute it, but the interpreter behaves as if nothing has happened. Yes, I saved the file and when I modified it by adding print statements then the changes still showed up, but the same voodoo code was executed. Why?

What's going on over here?

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
print txt.read()

print "I'll also ask you to type it again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

Comment: Is it not so that a compiled version <module>.pyc still exists?

Comment: How are you running this code? Are you using an IDE or the command line?

Comment: I am using command line to run it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That the program asks for the file name even though you have removed the part after `print txt.read()`? Can you also post your modified code so we can see what exactly is being run?

Comment: Anna, I'm not sure I understand your question. What was the code before the modification? What _did_ it do?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't clarify my question, but I didn't have internet access over the past week... 

The problem is that it still asks for the file name even if the portion after print txt.read() is deleted. The thing is that the code executes identically before and after execution. 

Why?

Comment: Instead of the hard way, take the _right_ way, read [`Dive into Python`](http://www.diveintopython.net/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably executing a different file then the one you are editing.